# How to store a tag value in local storage and how to fetch from local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I want to store value of anchor tag in local storage whichever is clicked and I want fetch on load in jquery then I need to add class for that clicked value as "active" how to do this?

Below is HTML code,

```html
<div class="flDropDiv category_fl">
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" value="Full bed sheets  " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/full-bed-sheets"> Full bed sheets   </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" value="Fitted bed Sheet " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/fitted-bed-sheet"> Fitted bed Sheet  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" value="Flat bed sheet " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/flat-bed-sheet"> Flat bed sheet  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" value="Twin bed sheet " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/twin-bed-sheet"> Twin bed sheet  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" value="Twinxl bed sheets  " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/twinxl-bed-sheets"> Twinxl bed sheets   </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" value="Queen bed sheet " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/queen-bed-sheet"> Queen bed sheet  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" value="King bed sheets " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/king-bed-sheets"> King bed sheets  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" value="Cal king bed sheets " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/cal-king-bed-sheets"> Cal king bed sheets  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" value="Duvet covers " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/duvet-covers"> Duvet covers  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" value="Bed skirts " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/bed-skirts"> Bed skirts  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" value="Standard Pillow cases " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/standard-pillow-cases"> Standard Pillow cases  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" value="King Pillow cases " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/king-pillow-cases"> King Pillow cases  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" value="Pillow shells " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/pillow-shells"> Pillow shells  </a> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: include what you have tried so far

Comment: so you want the code to remember what link youve clicked

Comment: Do you want to make your clicked anchor tag as active??

Comment: @immortal dude yes

Comment: @teemu I have included value for a tag please check it

Answer (score 1):

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/p4k3yg9o/2/)

Set and Get value on local storage. And for active class use add/remove class.

```
 $(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
  $(this).prop('href')
  localStorage.setItem('Url', $(this).prop('href'));
  alert(localStorage.getItem('Url'));
  $("a").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).prop('href') === localStorage.getItem('Url'))
      $(this).addClass('newanchor');
    else
      $(this).removeClass('newanchor');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
var localStorageIndex = "clickedLink";
$(function() {
  $(".category_filter").click(function(e) {
    if($(e.target).hasClass("active")){
    return;
    }

    var clickedLink = getActiveLinkFromLocalStorage();
    if(clickedLink !== e.target.href){
      clickedLink = e.target.href;
        $(e.target).addClass("active");
        localStorage.setItem(localStorageIndex, clickedLink);
    }
  })

  function getActiveLinkFromLocalStorage() {
    return localStorage.getItem(localStorageIndex);
  }

  function initActiveLink(){
    var clickedLink = getActiveLinkFromLocalStorage();
    if(!clickedLink){
        return;
    }
    $("a[href='" + clickedLink + "'].category_filter").addClass("active");
  }
  initActiveLink();
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4rnq214/11/)

Comment: it is working fine but when I click on again it should hide active class and also when I comeback means it should clear from localstorage.

Comment: @Mohan please notice all requirements in the future.
What do you mean when say "when I comeback"?

Answer (score 0):

localStorage access is pretty easy just use

```
localStorage.setItem('key', value)
```

and

```
localStorage.getItem('key')
```